# When passing dictionary from Flask to Jinja, the template outputs the whole dictionary, but cant output a single item

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, jinja2

On flask I made a dictionary which takes information from a form and appends them into the dictionary, called `dic`. When I try to print the whole dictionary (`dic`), it prints everything properly. Code for it below.

app.py

```
@app.route("/invoice", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def inv():
    dic = {'iname': [], 'iemail': [], 'iphone': [], 'iadr': [], 'iitem': [],
          'ides': [], 'iqnt': [], 'iprice': [], 'itax': [], 'itotal': []}
        if request.method == "POST":
            iname = str(request.form["Iname"])
            iemail = str(request.form["Iemail"])
            iphone = str(request.form["Iphone"])
            iadr = str(request.form["Iaddress"])
            iitem = str(request.form["Iitem"])
            ides = str(request.form["Ides"])
            iqnt = int(request.form["Iqnt"])
            iprice = float(request.form["Iprice"])
            itax = float(request.form["Itax"])
            itotal = float((iqnt * iprice) + itax)
    
            dic['iname'].append(iname)
            dic['iemail'].append(iemail)
            dic['iphone'].append(iphone)
            dic['iadr'].append(iadr)
            dic['iitem'].append(iitem)
            dic['ides'].append(ides)
            dic['iqnt'].append(iqnt)
            dic['iprice'].append(iprice)
            dic['itax'].append(itax)
            dic['itotal'].append(itotal)
            return redirect(url_for("invoicepdf", dic=dic))
        else:
            return render_template("invoice.html")
    

    @app.route("/<dic>")
    def invoicepdf(dic):
        rendered = render_template("inv_temp2.html", dic=dic)
        return rendered
```

HTML Code:

```
<p><span class="fw-bold" style="margin-right: 15px;">Billed To: </span>{{ dic }}</p>
```

html template output:

```
Billed To: {'iname': ['Alister'], 'iemail': ['alister@mail.com'], 'iphone': ['0123456789'],
 'iadr': ['on Earth'], 'iitem': ['IP12PRO'], 'ides': ['Iphone 12 Pro'], 'iqnt': [1], 'iprice': [2999.0],
 'itax': [400.0], 'itotal': ['3399.0']}
```

But when I am trying to print an individual item from the dictionary, it's not showing..(its blank). here is the html code for it:

```
<p><span class="fw-bold" style="margin-right: 15px;">Billed To: </span>{{ dic['iname'] }}</p>
<p><span class="fw-bold" style="margin-right: 15px;">Billed To: </span>{{ dic.iname }}</p>
```

template Output (no dictionary items are outputted):

```
Billed To:
Billed To:
```

Please help me, I'm trying my best to debug this, but stuck on it for days.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you render the template (GET on `/invoice`), you dont pass the `dic` parameter :)

**Solution**:

```py
return render_template("invoice.html", dic=dic)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your method and added the "dic=dic" at the end of the `else:` statement of the `/invoice` function. but it still isn't working.

Comment: I just noticed something else in your question : all dict values are list ! Therefore, you need to [iterate over it](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-control-structures) to render each value, or [make a join](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#join).
Its a strange behavior ; are you really need to use all theses values (iname, iemail) as lists ?

Comment: @Roman, yes my friend, I need to use all these values, I'm working on making a complex invoicing system..

Comment: Ok :)
So, in the template, you must do something like this : `{{ dic.iname | join(', ') }}`

Comment: Hi @Roman, I did what you the `{{ dic.iname | join(', ') }}` just like you suggested, still no results.

Comment: I guess I don't have any other choice but to give up using the dictionary,.. I have to manually send all the data individually.

Comment: My mistake, dic is a dictionary, so its `{{ dic['iname'] | join(', ') }}` :) (dot is for objects)

Comment: But maybe your datastructure is upside down : you have a dict of list, but in fact, you should use a list of dict. Email, name, phone,... all of that is correlated. You should probably do: `values=[{'iname': 'x', 'iphone': '00'}, {'iname': 'y', 'iphone': '11'}...]` and pass this values in a template loop